# document.getElementById to href click

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" nowrap="" class="formDatanobrdr">
    <a href="https://wapking.net" onclick="redirectToHandler();">Click here</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

They Are Not Click By Using the Below Code Please Tell how can i click the link

```
document.getElementsByName('formDatanobrdr')[0].click();
```

Comment: You're using `getElementsByName` but none of the elements have a `name` attribute (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName).

Comment: see the difference between `getElementsByName` and `getElementsByClassName`. You are using `getElementsByName` and do you see any attribute named "name" in your problem statement? Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: why you use ElementsByName but at your question says ElementById? if you use element by ID would be better... you just have to add an ID to the link , but I dont understand why you want to capture if you are triggering a method on the "onclick" as well

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByName` searches for elements with a specific `name=` attribute, which your html does not contain.

Instead search by class to access the td tag:

```
var td = document.getElementsByClassName("formDatanobrdr")[0];
//then select the a tag. its the only child element:   
var link = td.children[0];   
//click it
link.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `getElementsByClassName` it get all elements with the specified class name, also you need to click the a `tag` not the table row tag so add new class to a tag

```
<tr><td colspan="2" nowrap="" class="formDatanobrdr">
<a  class="formDatanobrdr1" href="https://wapking.net" onclick="redirectToHandler();">Click here</a></td></tr>

<script>document.getElementsByClassName('formDatanobrdr1')[0].click();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

querySelector can select one Element (the first in DOM corresponding to query)
So I give you the better unique query with your info

```js
document.querySelector('tr > td.formDatanobrdr > a[href="https://wapking.net"]').click();
```

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" nowrap="" class="formDatanobrdr">
    <a href="https://wapking.net" onclick="redirectToHandler();">Click here</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```